# django - how to make clickable html text that sends data to model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to display users around 10 clickable html "tags" (just text with some css that changes when clicked) on my form page. I want them to be able to select a maximum of 3 tags but no minimum requirement. I then want to take the sum of all clicks for each individual tag and do some calculations with them as a model method, like return the 3 most clicked tags.

It's important that my tags are on the form page and are submitted at the same time as the form. So I guess they have to be part of my form.

How would I go about doing this? An actual example would be tremendously helpful as I'm still very new to django and find the documentation (which I've looked at) somewhat hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the tags ahead of time, I'd recommend this setup:

- Use a multiple select widget in your form (see the `favorite_colors` field in [this Django widgets example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets))
- Use [Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox) or another JavaScript library that converts `<select multiple>` inputs into a tags-like UI

If you go that route, [this widget from django-select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#django_select2.forms.Select2MultipleWidget) looks like it should get you off to the races.

Comment: i'm looking into it. In Django Widgets Example, they have the multiple choices setup in the forms.py file. I got it to work, but I am trying to figure out how to connect that to my model so I can do some mathematical operations with user inputs later on? Should I have each tag as a .BooleanField in my model? Or is there another route?